# excel NPV does not work properly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

let us consider following example

```
Example: Invest $2,000 now, receive 3 yearly payments of $100 each, plus $2,500 in the 3rd year. Use 10% Interest Rate.
Let us work year by year (remembering to subtract what you pay out):
Now: PV = -$2,000
Year 1: PV = $100 / 1.10 = $90.91
Year 2: PV = $100 / 1.102 = $82.64
Year 3: PV = $100 / 1.103 = $75.13
Year 3 (final payment): PV = $2,500 / 1.103 = $1,878.29
Adding those up gets: NPV = -$2,000 + $90.91 + $82.64 + $75.13 + $1,878.29 = $126.97
Looks like a good investment.
```

i have tried to calculate same in excel

```
10%
100
100
100
2500
-2000
```

`=NPV(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)+A6`

and got  (43.78),why?please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to net your final year - 100 + 2500

The NPV function assumes each cell value is the money recieved at the end of its own year.

It is assuming that you are getting the 2500 a year after the last 100 dollar payment.

try this instead:

```
100
100
2600
```

NPV(.10,100,100,2600)-2000 = ~126.97

Comment: it means that if i  add 2500 to  another cell,it will calculate for 4 year?

Comment: yes, the number of cells included in the function determines the length of the investment (in periods). This is to simplify the function - all it needs to know is the net cash out/in at the end of each period.

Comment: thanks for help,just one additional question  why we are adding negative term directly and not use this value in npv box?i meant if i enter  negative term in  function as well it would calculate  different result

Comment: also  happy christmas for  yesterday  25 december and  happy new year for advance,wish you everything best

Comment: It all depends on the assumptions you are making - including it as the first value in your function assumes you output it at the end of the first year(the same time you get your first 100 dollar payment). Whereas subtracting it directly assumes you are paying it out immediately(at the beginning of the first year). see here for examples of the two assumptions: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/npv-HP005209199.aspx - happy holidays/merry christmas